# How set a class to a li tag by its index in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add or remove a class of a `li` by its index:

e.g: add the class `.active` to the `li` of index 2 or 
remove class of a `li` of index 0, using `jQuery`.

how can I do that by `jQuery` query?

ps: I added a snippet with a possible scenario.

```js
// query to set a class to a li by its index
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list" class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">5</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I aready tried a `$("#list li").forEach...` but i guess there is a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```js
$('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
$('li:eq(3)').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active a {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" >1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">5</a></li>       
</ul>
```

Comment: dude! that exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.eq`.

```
$('#list li').eq(li_position);
```

You can see the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function will reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

To add a class to `<li>` with index of `2`, simply use:

```
$('#list li').eq(2).addClass('myClass');
```

Alternatively, you may use the [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector as follows, to reduce the number of function calls:

```
$('#list li:eq(2)').addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: Thats awesome , the first way is way better way for doing it! Thanks!!